# How do I apply Thevenin theorem in this problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, thevenin

Can't find the answer to this question. Am I supposed to get the voltage in the 4 kilo ohm resistor? Really appreciate it if anyone can solve this one! Here's the circuit:

[image: find V0 by thevenin method]

Comment: There is only one question here, and the answer is **Yes**.  For the request to solve your homework problem, we don't do that here.  But we can help you.  Show us what you have tried, and we can give you pointers and direction.

Comment: Just for future reference: you have a voltage *across* and a current *through* a resistor. You do not have a voltage *in* a resistor.

Comment: @Aaron Thing is my instructor is recording lectures from his PC screen and sending them to us by moodle. But i'm not able to understand anything from his video lectures. Plus, he's giving us graded assignments. You're right it's really not "cool" to come here and just ask for someone to solve my homework. Anyways, what i understood from the video is that by using thevenin, we can remove the 12V voltage source and we can remove the 2mA current source and replace it with an open circuit. What are the steps in order to get V0 which is = to the voltage across the 4 kilo ohm resistor?

Comment: @Oldfart right lol. thanks!

Comment: You can google Thevenin also.  You need to treat the current source and voltage source differently.

Comment: It sounds like your instructor has a very specific method that he wants you to use to solve this problem. I teach university level circuits and it is not clear to me what exactly you are supposed to do. Maybe source transformation? In any event, you really need to contact the instructor and ask for help.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Nope, he actually stated in the video that we should not use source transformation. Only thevenin. Thanks though :)

Comment: You can use superposition and get the voltage in a few easy steps: determine the voltage Vo1 when the 2-mA source is open circuited while the 12-V is alive. Then, determine the voltage Vo2 when the 12-V source is shorted while the 2-mA source is alive. The voltage you want is \$V_{th}=V_{o1}+V_{o2}\$. For \$R_{th}\$, short the 12-V source and open-circuit the 2-mA source. Then "look" at the resistance seen from the 4-kohm terminals. It should be \$R_{th}= 4k || ... \$ and quite easy to determine.

Comment: Remove the 4k resistor. Now the two halves of the circuit can be treated as though they are independent. So calculate V+ using a simple potential divider and V- from 2mA flowing through 2k. This gives VT of 12V. Next short the voltage source, remove the current source and calculate RT which is the resistance between the terminals. RT = 4k. Draw your Thevenin equiv cct with the 4k load replaced and calculate load voltage using potential divider law. Vout = 6V.

Comment: @James Got it! Thank you,problem was that i reached to the 12V part but didn't know how to continue. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to determine these values. I personally like superposition a lot because it is already part of the *divide-and-conquer* strategy promoted by the fast analytical techniques or FACTs. Here, superposition applies because we obviously deal with a linear circuit. We thus determine the voltage \$V_{th2}\$ across the 4-\$k\Omega\$ resistor when the 12-V source is turned off (a 0-V source is replaced by a short circuit) while the current source is alive. Then, we turn the current source off (a 0-A current source is an open circuit) and determine the voltage \$V_{th1}\$ when the 12-V is alive. At the end, we have \$V_{th}=V_{th1}+V_{th2}\$

We can now divide the circuit in sketches you can individually resolve:

[image]

In the upper sketch, we can use a Thévenin generator to determine the circulating current while the current source is off. Then, in the sketch below, shorting the voltage source simplifies the arrangement with two paralleled resistors. Use the current division property to obtain the voltage across \$R_3\$. If you enter your equations in a solver like Mathcad (see below) you find a Thévenin voltage of 6 V by summing both intermediate values:

[image]

To determine the Thévenin resistance, you can apply the FACTs because we have a linear circuit: turn all excitation sources off (12-V is shorted and the 2-mA is open circuited) then "look" at the resistance across the Thévenin terminals (across \$R_3\$). You see that this resistance is actually \$R_3\$ in parallel with some intermediate result the last sketch lets you find in a second, without an equation:

\$R_{int}=R_2||R_1+R_4\$ then bring \$R_3\$ back and you have \$R_{th}=R_3||(R_2||R_1+R_4)\$.

A quick SPICE simulation of the operating point confirms these results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Well explained appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps!